# What is the best way to implement material design in pre-lollipop devices?

Tags: android, android-support-library, material-design, android-design-library

I have to make my app fully in material design. It should support pre-lollipop devices as well. I tried with one [support library found here](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary).

It works fine, but seems to be slow in effects like ripple effects. In some articles, I found we can use

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+1"
```

This dependency [like here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html).

What is the right way to implement material design on older devices? 
I want to use material items, like Floating action button and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaterialDesignLibrary by navasmdc seems to be forgoten with 150+ issues reported. It's also known for its conflicts with other libraries, lack of support and poor widget implementation.

Basically it depends on what would you like to achieve. Most of material features is too heavy to be used on older platforms. If you wish to have FloatingActionButton, Toolbar, RecyclerView and theming, you can use the [Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and AppCompat from Google.

If you wish to have shadows, ripples and others, you should look for open-source libraries. [Ray's lib](https://github.com/rey5137/material) is a very good example. Check out [awesome-android](https://github.com/snowdream/awesome-android#Material) and [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/). Both have a good list of material libraries.

I have my own library as well. It's called [Carbon](https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon) and it backports most of material features to Android 2.2+.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the [support design library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), for [ripple effects](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) and other good features use [rey material library](https://github.com/rey5137/material), you can also see [navasmdc](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary)

Comment: Right now I'm using  [navasmdc](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) . But the problem there is ripple effect is so slow. can I use more than one dependency?

Comment: yes you can use more then one dependency, i have used rey material in my app and i can control animation time app:mrl_rippleDuration="350"              // duration of ripple animation
app:mrl_rippleFadeDuration="75"           // duration of fade out effect on ripple, i am sure there must be some attribute that you can use to control the animation speed other wise rey is a good go

Comment: in which dependency `app:mrl_rippleDuration="350" ` this is used?

Comment: this is a example of https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple but i am sure this attribute must be available for others too

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to implement material design is to use open source libraries that supports all pre-lollipop devices.

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) and [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs).

There are many other libraries as well. You can google it.