# Material Design on Pre-Lollipop Devices Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to develop an Android application based on Material Design. I want to support the pre-Lollipop devices.

I found the `AppCompat` library and tried to follow guides and tutorials but nothing seemed to work. Most of them are focused on Android Studio while I need to use the Eclipse IDE.

I am following guidance from this post on [AppCompat](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), this post on the [Android Material Design support library](http://techlovejump.com/android-material-design-support-library/) and this [Android Toolbar tutorial](http://techlovejump.com/android-toolbar-tutorial/)

Unfortunately, `ActionBarActivity` is deprecated. I've tried to "update" my project as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890530/actionbaractivity-is-deprecated-android-studio)).

I don't recive any errors on the Eclipse console, but when I open the app on my Smartphone (Samsung Galaxy Ace 4 with Android 4.4.4) a popup icon appears saying `application has unexpectedly quit`, and I receive the `InvocationTargetException` error.

The only solution that works is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29240839/android-material-design-in-eclipse), but it does not support pre-Lollipop devices (only API 21 and higher).

I finally tried to use a different support library found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428138/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-material-design-in-pre-lollipop-devices), but I don't know how to use the "Ray's lib" library.

All I want to do is something similar to Google apps that use Material Design on pre-Lollipop devices. Is there any way to do this? Can someone help me?

If I can't on Eclipse, is there a way to do that in Android Studio?

Comment: Eclipse isn't support anymore for Android development. You have to move to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) as it is the official Android's IDE.

If you are starting a new project, and you want to use material design on pre-lollipop devices stick to the appCompat just include these on your graddle dependecies and use AppCompat components on your project.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

It's important to note that not every material component has backwards compatibility. For some elements you may need to use third party libraries or create your custom components.