# Material design for pre-lollipop devices

Tags: android

I'm a Newbie to Android Programming,I want to use Material design for pre-lollipop devices,What are the things do i have to consider if I want my app to run on most Android devices?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What material design you want to use?  `specify clearly`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428138/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-material-design-in-pre-lollipop-devices

Comment: you have to extend your activities from AppCompatActivity which is the default style in creating new projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can get working pretty much all of the features of material design through AppCompat (even the Floating action button!) I suggest you take a look at this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html?hl=en#v7.

Just make sure you are using the appcompat by adding it to your dependencies in your gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Read proper [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html) of Android Material design

For Material Design You have to use

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0
```

Try to Follow [Tutorial 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/)   Hope this will help you.!